# After adding `runValidators: true`, my Mongoose update function is erroring with ` cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null `

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Thank you in advance for any help that anyone can provide.

I currently have something like below for my mongoose schema:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    unique: true
  },
  number: {
    type: String, 
    validate: {
      // below regex matches 8 digits together regardless of any other characters in between that are not digits
      validator: function(v) { return /([^\d]*\d){8,}/.test(v) }
    },
    required: true
  },
})

// applying the uniqueness validator 
personSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)

personSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema)
```

And in my index.js for my function for handling update calls, it looks like this:

```
app.put('/api/persons/:id', (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body 

  const person = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number,
  }
  
  Person.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, {new: true})
    .then(updatedPerson => {
      response.json(updatedPerson) 
    })
    .catch(error => next(error))
})
```

So initially, this worked perfectly fine, but after I add the `runValidators: true` option which looks like this now:

`Person.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, {new: true, runValidators: true,})`

I get this new error that states:

`"error": "Validation failed: name: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"`

I'm not sure what ownerDocument even is, and I'm also unclear on why making the update function run the validator is causing this  as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `mongoose-unique-validator` plugin with `findOneAndUpdate` and related methods, you need to set the `context` option to `'query'` to set the value of `this` to the `query` object in validators.

```
Person.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, {
  new: true, 
  runValidators: true,
  context: 'query',
})
```

https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator#find--updates